# How to get the consecutive Lead numbers like LEA4 in Vtiger crm

Tags: php, vtiger

I want the code to generate the consecutive Lead numbers like LEA4 . Where to get the code ?

Comment: Can you explain more about your question?

Answer (score 2):

1-> create the one fileds in module and set the UITYPE=4

2-> go to crm setting and find the "Customize Record Numbering"

3-> select the module of the rightside picklist

4-> set the user prefix and start sequence

thats it....vtiger crm by default provides the auto generate on save the nuber in every record creation....